# Ruby gsub, NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, out-of-memory

We have a html template cached - which has placeholder values. Based on the real object values, the placeholders are being replaced. This works fine mostly but sometimes results in error(failed to allocate memory).

```
    replacement_hash.keys.each do |placeholder|
      value = ##some logic to get values from model using placeholder text.
      text.gsub!(placeholder, value)
    end
```

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed(made more efficient) or any alternate ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: We need the exact error output (line that raises the exception) and the full code (including the login that's commented out), in order to help you.

Comment: okay sure @Agis, thanks for the comment. Line I mentioned as gsub is where error is raised. commented code is class.send(:placeholder) kind of logic which will get value from database. Do you believe the combined code results in high memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to bad user data - string containing invalid values - which resulted gsub to work incorrectly and same string which was to be replaced by gsub was inserted back again.

And code had a recursive function which will continue replacing things until no string with [[xxx]] is present - this caused the code to go into a loop until memory was full.

```
"Kiprosh [[signature]]".gsub("[[signature]]", "\0 and \0")
expected =>  "Kiprosh \0 and \0"
actual   => "Kiprosh [[signature]] and [[signature]]"
```